# How do i increment and view cart items in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello please I am new to react and trying to build a checkout system via fake store API where users can view items in cart , increase item's count , reduce item's count and clear cart. So far I have rendered the products on main page. But I don't know how to increment item cart and view items in cart. I know this might be an easy task but I don't know how to proceed and I am trying to avoid video tutorials. please any advice on how to proceed is appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      
      this.state = {
          products: [],
          count: 0 
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
 axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
 .then(response =>{
     const products = response.data
     this.setState({products})
     console.log(products)
 } )
 
 .catch(err=> console.log(err))
  }

  incrementCart = () =>{
 this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
  }   
  
  
  render() {
      return (
          <div id="container">
         {
        this.state.products.map(product=> 
             <div id="product" key={product.id}>
              <img className="img" src={product.image} alt="product-store"/>
              <h1>{product.category}</h1>
               <h4>{product.price}</h4>
               <button onClick={this.incrementCart}>Add To Cart</button>
             </div>
            
         )    
         }
         
          </div>

      )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: just posted the example with cart implementation, do check out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you are able to render products on your main page, you should be able to do the same for the cart, but only changing the way it is rendered ( layout/template/component.. ) and about the count what is it that you doing wrong ? Is it actually incrementing ? If so you just have to render it in the right place ( your cart / navbar whatever ) ..

I think it is pretty much the same has you have accomplished right now but you'd just have to render the data on your cart component instead ? and then have a way to show/hide that cart component ?

Edit:

I get it, I think you are incrementing in the component state but you are not saving that state globally so you can not access it on another component/page or after page refresh?

I think you have a few options, one of them would be Sending a GET/POST request to and ENDPOINT that will Add the Product ID to the Cart, and in other pages/components you would have to Send a GET/POST request that instead of saving, will retrieve the data from the Cart ( Product Ids left joined ( for ex) with Users ) that you had previously saved.

You could also use the "localStorage" to save the cart items / products data:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage

There are other options too I guess, but these seem to be easiest and most logic solutions to me!

Comment: in the main page attached to each product is a button(`add to cart`) and at the click of button(`add to cart`) count value increment but i want to code it such that at the click of a product button(`add to cart`) on main page , cart count should Increment and also the product should be displayed in cart too.

Comment: hey @AdegbiteAdemola I have edited my answer, please check, i suggest saving the cart products in a database ( for example ) by making a GET/POST request, and then when you need to items you do a GET/POST request o retrieve the previously saved cart products! Or you could just save it in the localStorage but I guess that has some limitations and you wouldn't have data saved into your database for example for later analysis.

Answer (score 2):

**Final Output:**

[image]

To store the products in a cart when clicked `add to cart` button, we are using the following `addtoCart()` function, which takes product object as an argument.

When the button is clicked, this function is called and in this function we are incrementing the cart item count and adding the provided `product` object in our `cart` array.

```
addtoCart = (product) => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
      cart: this.state.cart.concat(product)
    });
    console.log(this.state.cart);
  };
```

Now we can use these two states(`count` and `cart`) to render the cart items using `map` method with the help of below code:

```
{this.state.products.length > 0 && (
          <div className="cart">
            <p>{this.state.count}</p>
            {this.state.cart?.map((item) => (
              <div className="itemBox">
                <div style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
                  <img className="cartImage" src={item.image} />
                </div>
                <div> {item?.title.substr(0, 10) + "..."}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
```

**Final Finished source code:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: [],
      count: 0,
      cart: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
      .then((response) => {
        const products = response.data;
        this.setState({ products });
        console.log(products);
      })

      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  addtoCart = (product) => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
      cart: this.state.cart.concat(product)
    });
    console.log(this.state.cart);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="container">
          {this.state.products.length ? (
            this.state.products.map((product) => (
              <div className="productContainer" id="product" key={product.id}>
                <img className="img" src={product.image} alt="product-store" />
                <h1>{product.category}</h1>
                <h4>{product.price}</h4>
                <button onClick={() => this.addtoCart(product)}>
                  Add To Cart
                </button>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <div className="productContainer">
              <p>Loading</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        {this.state.products.length > 0 && (
          <div className="cart">
            <p>{this.state.count}</p>
            {this.state.cart?.map((item) => (
              <div className="itemBox">
                <div style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
                  <img className="cartImage" src={item.image} />
                </div>
                <div> {item?.title.substr(0, 10) + "..."}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-pine-7rhmz?file=/src/App.js)